# Typescript dynamic access property

Tags: typescript

Here is a demo:

```
class Vec2 {};
class Vec3 {};
class Vec4 {};

let mylibs = {
    Vec2: Vec2,
    Vec3: Vec3,
    Vec4: Vec4
};
let len = Math.round(Math.random() * 2) + 2;
let VecType = 'Vec' + len;
let randomVector = new mylibs[VecType]();
```

I want to create something by user input, the `VecType` is something I used to simulate user input.
The code above works, and `tsc` will not throw any error. However in my vscode, it tell me something wrong.

[image]
[image]

I want to resolve this kind of error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests one solution would be to add an index signature to the type so as to allow indexing by any string :

```
let mylibs : { [key: string]:  new () => any} = {
    Vec2: Vec2,
    Vec3: Vec3,
    Vec4: Vec4
};
```

Instead of any if you want to be more restrictive, you could use a base class of the `Vec*` types, or a union type of all property types (`Vec2|Vec3|Vec4`)

Another option, would be to not index by a generic string but rather by a string that is a key for `mylibs`. To construct such a string dynamically would involve a cast which would not be particularly safe:

```
let VecType: keyof typeof mylibs = ('Vec' + len) as any;
let randomVector = new mylibs[VecType]();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question: If `mylibs` has many other properties/utils, like: `mylibs.utils.request`, `mylibs.constants.X`, which solution is better ?

Comment: I finally figure out it: `let VecType: 'Vec2' | 'Vec3' | 'Vec4' = 'Vec' + len as any;`.

Comment: Both solutions can be used .. but it's not ideal, I will update my answer shortly

Comment: @user2331095, Yup that was what I was going to say as well :). You can use the index solution as well but the index will return `any` instead of `new ()=>any`