# Typescript using property accessors doesn't resolve interface

Tags: typescript

I've found this similar problem, however it does not fully solve my problem [Typescript dynamic access property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417520/typescript-dynamic-access-property).

Since I'm new to Typescript I tried to create a program which takes in an object and then pushes the key + value pair into an array.

Here I don't quite understand the Errors Typescript is throwing.

#1 Why do i need to explicitly say `[key:string]`, leaving it out leads to the Error at line #1.5 `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ProductSearch'`?

#2 Here I get the Error `Argument of type 'ProductSearch' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`, shouldn't the type of the value be resolved to 'string'?

Using product.productId for example does not throw an error.

```js
import { ProductSearch } from "../typings/ProductSearch";

// export interface ProductSearch {
//   productId: string
//   productBrand: string
//   producerProductId: string
//   productType: string
//   productGtin: string
//   productStatus: string
//   productGroup: string
//   productDesc: string
//   poductFreetext: string
// }

async function test(product: { [key: string]: ProductSearch }) { // #1
  const params: string[] = [];
  Object.keys(product).forEach((key) => {
    const value = product[key]; // #1.5
    if (value) {
      params.push(key, value); // #2
    }
  });
```

EDIT

I was able to solve it by adding [key: string]: string; as last line of the Interface, I will gladly accept an answer explaining, why this solves the Problem, i can use the key to get the value and the value is correctly of type string.

Comment: for #1, did you try product : ProductSearch ?

Comment: params is a string array. why are you pushing a key, value in there ?

Comment: Hey Dhruv, yes i tried product: ProductSearch, I've only used the string array as an example. My main issue here was i didn't understand why value was not resolved to string

Comment: Why do you push two values to the array `params.push(key, value);` ?  Your `value` has ProductSearch type and `key` is string and you expect only strings in `params` variable.
I think your logic is incorrect

Comment: Then i might not understand how typescript works, why would value be of type ProductSearch? I take the Key from the Object for example "productId" and then assign the value with value = product["productId"] which is declared as a string in the interface. This code is perfectly valid in Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Type `{ [key: string]: ProductSearch }` means that object has string key and ProductSearch `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of incoherences but basically, this doesn't work:

```
async function test(product: ProductSearch) { // #1
  const params: string[] = [];
  Object.keys(product).forEach((key) => {
    const value = product[key]; // #1.5
    if (value) {
      params.push(key, value); // #2
    }
  });
```

Why? because product can be only be queried by the keys of product. String means that you can use whatever string you please to query your object which will result in an undefined value if the key doesn't exist.

Try this and see for yourself:

```
async function test(product: ProductSearch) { // #1
  const params: string[] = [];
  Object.keys(product).forEach((key) => {
    const value = product[key as keyof ProductSearch]; // Hurrah, Typescript doesn't complain anymore!
    if (value) {
      params.push(key, value); // #2
    }
  });
```

The thing is that `Object.keys(product)` returns `string[]` (the type should be `keyof product`, I don't know why it is typed as string[]...). Edit: found this ([Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/11758901))

By the way, `params.push(key, value);` just appends key and value as two distinct values to your array. In the end, you'll have something like this: `['productId', 'productIdValue', 'productBrand', 'productBrandValue']` Is that really what you want to do? Don't you want instead something like this: `[{productId: 'productIdValue'}, {productBrand: 'productBrandValue'}]`? In which case, you have an array of key:value pairs and not strings.

And last but not least, `[key: string]: ProductSearch` means that the object you pass as a prop looks more something like this:

```
{
  key1: {
    productId: 'value1',
    productBrand: 'value2',
    ...etc
  },
  key2: {
    productId: 'value1',
    productBrand: 'value2',
    ...etc
  }
}
```

It is not clear to me, so that's the best I can do to help.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, this is what I was looking for, as I didn't understand why a key from Object.keys was not accepted as key when accessing the Object. About params.push(), I just created it as example to show in which cases the error occures

Answer (score 1):

Use a map.

```
async function test(product: Map<string, ProductSearch>) {
```

### Edit

I'm quite unsure what you exactly want. So according to your sentence

> [...] which takes in an object and then pushes the values into an array.

```
async function test(products: Map<string, ProductSearch>) {
  let params = products.values(); // <- this give you all values in your map
}
```

If I am wrong, can you explain what you want?

Comment: Using Map results in Error #1: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ProductSearch'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ProductSearch

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you clarify what you want, if the answer is wrong?

Comment: What i needed was the key + value pair, however my main Problem were the errors ts gave me, which were solved by your answer.